# A single word for "liking someone's speech/quote/idea"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I usally hear the word compounds "well-said, well-spoken etc.." to express the appreciation of someone's speech or a useful idea, but I never heard such a single word to express that.

PS : I'm not searching for answers like : "To agree etc..." or general terms of "admitting/accepting things".

**EDIT** : I've found a useful interjection "[Touche](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/touche)", but still wondering if it can be used in business speech.

Comment: Good, great, wonderful, excellent...may well express appreciation!!

Comment: I'm immediately reminded of [Blazing Saddles](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JN99jshaQbY) which uses the term *harrumph*; but apparently their usage is incorrect, as the definition is *to disagree*.

Comment: @PatrickM _harrumph_ is far away from what I'm asking for, 'cause it means '_to comment disapprovingly_' not to appreciate a speech.

Comment: @medica , and Josh61 please read my "PS" above. I'm not searching for general terms of admitting or agreeing.

Comment: So you want one word that expresses *specifically* the same as "well-said", "well-put", "beautifully-stated", etc.?

Comment: What's the context here? Why did you need one word? Applause works but that's zero words.

Comment: 'Amen' isn't just for Sundays.

Comment: "Amen" is probably the best answer. By the way, "well-spoken" means something else, to me.

Comment: *Bravo!* (or *Brava! Bravi! Brave!*, depending on the sex and number of the person or persons applauded) is traditional in the performing arts.

Comment: I've edited the description:)

Comment: *Touché* comes from fencing (the sport, not outdoor boundary-marking), and indicates that you acknowledge a successful hit from your opponent. It's used when someone says something telling **against you** which you sheepishly accept. It's not a saying indicating approbation.

Answer (score 2):

*Brilliant* is commonly used to refer in glowing terms to speeches/ideas.

Answer (score 2):

'eloquent' might be the word you are looking for.