# What is this usage of harrumph?

Tags: meaning, idioms

So [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185286) was just asked and it made me realize I didn't understand what was going on [this particular movie scene](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JN99jshaQbY) (Mel Brooks' 1974 *Blazing Saddles*).

Transcript:

> **Governor William J. Le Petomane:** Holy underwear! Sheriff murdered! Innocent women and children blown to bits! We have to protect our phoney baloney jobs here, gentlemen! We must do something about this immediately! Immediately! Immediately! Harrumph! Harrumph! Harrumph!
>
> **Governor William J. Le Petomane:** *[pointing to a member of his cabinet]* I didn't get a "harrumph" out of that guy!
>
> **Hedley Lamarr:** Give the Governor harrumph!
>
> **Politician:** Harrumph!

Anyways, I thought that harrumph could be used to voice general agreement to or approval of what was just said. This is incorrect. [Merriam-Webster's](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/harrumph) says this:

> *intransitive verb*
> **1:**  to clear the throat in a pompous way
> **2:**  to comment disapprovingly
> *transitive verb*
> **:**  to utter (a comment) disapprovingly

The actual meaning in this usage is the exact opposite of what I thought. So is there another accepted definition? Or is the governor and his cabinet **[standing] around *harrumphing* about the current state** of affairs? (from MW link above)

Or is that, as they say, [the joke](http://i1.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/012/132/thatsthejoke.jpg)?

Comment: Is that a transcript of a single conversation? If so, it seems to be an utterly bewildering and meaningless one out of context. I have no idea what any of these people are trying to say based on what you've quoted. _Harrumph_ is indeed a noise made to express disdain, not assent, or of course simply as an even more high-faluting way of saying “Ahem” or “Hem-hem” or “Hrm-hrm” (or however many other ways there are to spell someone clearing their throat). The more disdainfully offended you are, the more r’s you add. “I'll have none of that, thank you! Harrrrr-_rumph_!”

Comment: (Added after watching the video clip) Aha. Now I see what is meant. Here, “harrumph” is just meant to be a pompous sound indicating indignation, being all worked up, etc. Not truly disdain, more a ‘rousing cry’, so to speak. A kind of “Geronimo!” battle cry of self-righteously pompous indignation, if you will.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I agree with your 2nd comment. I just want to know if, say, OED has an obscure definition for that use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Governor is running through a bombastic tirade about things that make him unhappy. His *Harrumph* fits both definitions.

He is surrounded by *yes-men*, lackeys of no particular viewpoint or individual strength. He expects each and every one of them to be echoing his every expression, including his every *harrumph*.

Comment: Hmm, what you say follows my own thoughts on learning there wasn't a definition meaning "voicing agreement with discontent." I guess what I'm really driving at is: What is it called when you unintentionally disparage your argument or point of view through the mis-use of language?

Comment: Perhaps *your argument is [oxymoronic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/oxymoron#oxymoron), you moron*?

Answer (score 1):

While the official dictionary definition doesn't really agree with this, I always viewed this as the yes-men doing what yes-men do. Which is parroting and reinforcing the primary person's opinion without real thought of their own. The Governor says "harrumph" the yes-men say "harrumph." The governor actually uses it in the correct way, the yes-men parrot him. So they are agreeing with him by using a word that technically means they aren't. So in a way it is a subtle joke, among the many not so subtle jokes.

Answer (score 0):

No no no!  The word harumph was commonly spoken by actors forming "crowds" or "gatherings" in old movies to make it sound like there was background conversation happening. When spoken by many people at random, it sounded just like many persons conversing or mumuring.  And that, my friends, is the joke.

Comment: What is your source?

Comment: Welcome to our site! Please [edit] your answer to provide authoritative evidence to support this – otherwise, it might be viewed as potentially ill-informed personal opinion, which could attract downvotes. For more guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. :-)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).